# Trouble with MYSQL

Tags: java, mysql, phpmyadmin

<**Edited**>
I'm an intermediate Java programmer currently working with Java and MySQL to create an app. I'm using Xampp and the PHPMYAdmin that comes with it.
The server is on 127.0.0.1 without any routers,Wifi systems or network.My app is also on 127.0.0.1
Everytime I try to connect to MySQL using Java, this message is displayed:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link 
failure  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds 
ago.The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

But the MySQL server is running alright. When I log into PHPMYAdmin, these 
errors are shown:

```
    #2002 - Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network 
    address/port) 
    is normally permitted.
    — The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not 
    correctly configured).
    mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Only one usage of each socket 
    address 
    (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
    Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
    mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Only one usage of each socket 
    address 
    (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
    Retry to connect
    Warning in .\libraries\dbi\DBIMysqli.php#629
    mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean 
    given

    Backtrace

    .\libraries\dbi\DBIMysqli.php#629: mysqli_real_escape_string(
    boolean false,
    string 'root',
    )
    .\libraries\DatabaseInterface.php#2670: PMA\libraries\dbi\DBIMysqli- 
    >escapeString(
    boolean false,
    string 'root',
    )
    .\libraries\Menu.php#142: PMA\libraries\DatabaseInterface- 
    >escapeString(string 'root')
    .\libraries\Menu.php#110: PMA\libraries\Menu->_getAllowedTabs(string 
    'server')
    .\libraries\Menu.php#83: PMA\libraries\Menu->_getMenu()
    .\libraries\Response.php#316: PMA\libraries\Menu->getHash()
    .\libraries\Response.php#441: PMA\libraries\Response->_ajaxResponse()
    PMA\libraries\Response::response()
    Warning in .\libraries\dbi\DBIMysqli.php#629
    mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean 
    given

    Backtrace

   .\libraries\dbi\DBIMysqli.php#629: mysqli_real_escape_string(
   boolean false,
   string 'root',
   )
   .\libraries\DatabaseInterface.php#2670: PMA\libraries\dbi\DBIMysqli- 
   >escapeString(
   boolean false,
   string 'root', 
   )
   .\libraries\Menu.php#142: PMA\libraries\DatabaseInterface- 
   >escapeString(string 
   'root')
   .\libraries\Menu.php#110: PMA\libraries\Menu->_getAllowedTabs(string 
   'server')
   .\libraries\Menu.php#71: PMA\libraries\Menu->_getMenu()
   .\libraries\Response.php#327: PMA\libraries\Menu->getDisplay()
   .\libraries\Response.php#441: PMA\libraries\Response->_ajaxResponse()
   PMA\libraries\Response::response()
```

the mysql my.ini file:

```
[mysqld]
port= 3306
socket = "E:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
basedir = "E:/xampp/mysql" 
tmpdir = "E:/xampp/tmp" 
datadir = "E:/xampp/mysql/data"
pid_file = "mysql.pid"
# enable-named-pipe
key_buffer = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
log_error = "mysql_error.log"


plugin_dir = "E:/xampp/mysql/lib/plugin/" 

innodb_data_home_dir = "E:/xampp/mysql/data"
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir = "E:/xampp/mysql/data"
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M
innodb_log_file_size = 5M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash

[isamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

And heres how I connect to Java:

```
try{
Class.forName("java.sql.DriverManager");
Connection conn=  
(Connection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:// 
localhost:3306/","root","mypassword");
Statement stmt=(Statement)conn.createStatement();
}
catch(Exception e){/*handling*/}
```

Comment: At first sight is a configuration issue...
How it's configured in java? How's the config you have in my.ini? How do you call it in the app? Do you use a framework (like JPA) to connect? Do you use a proxy server?

Comment: I'm using JDBC I use a proxy.At 3306.Will post the my.ini in a sec.

Comment: To me this sounds like a spotty network. Is MySQL running in your local machine or a remote server? Are you connectiing over Ethernet or WiFi?

Comment: See if you can answer now.I've modified the question.